# WordPress Bedrock Advanced Custom Field as dependency

Tags: wordpress, composer-php, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-bedrock

I am setting up a WordPress site with BedRock and was thinking if there is a way to "require" the ACF plugin in my composer.

So the plan is to have clean and simple repo where you do a git pull and composer install and then everything gets installed (including plugins)

But I don't find any documentation on the ACF site on how to do this.

Is this even possible? lol

I found this package but it's for ACF Pro and I just need the free version.

https://github.com/PhilippBaschke/acf-pro-installer

If anyone has any experience with BedRock and can help me out that would be greatly appreciated :)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the wpackagist repository to Composer's "repositories", you can then require the ACF free version.

In Bedrock's `composer.json` add the wp-packagist repo:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://wpackagist.org"
    }
],
...
```

Then in the same file, require the plugin:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "composer/installers": "~1.0.12",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.0.1",
    "johnpbloch/wordpress": "4.7.2",
    "oscarotero/env": "^1.0",
    "roots/wp-password-bcrypt": "1.0.0",
    "roots/soil": "3.7.1",
    "wpackagist-plugin/advanced-custom-fields" : "4.1.*"
},
...
```

Run `composer update` and it should fetch the plugin.

Comment: How come I can find the package on wpackagist.org?

Comment: Can't answer that! Maybe their search function isn't great...wpackagist mirrors the public plugin directory, so the plugin slug with the version number as I've quoted above will work, so long as you include the wpackagist repository. I discovered this by trial and error, I also couldn't find ACF on wpackagist.org.

Comment: Yeah there is probably something wrong with there search function, I've been able to find it with including the dashes

Answer (score 0):

Side note, the https://github.com/PhilippBaschke/acf-pro-installer tool is no longer supported and doesn't work with Composer 2 or ACF versions  > 5.10.x

To fix the second issue with ACF versions, in src/ACFProInstaller/Plugin.php edit line 187 to:

```
$major_minor_patch_optional = '/\A\d\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}(?:\.\d)?\Z/';
```

For Composer 2 compatibility, see
https://github.com/pivvenit/acf-pro-installer and https://github.com/ffraenz/private-composer-installer are two options for replacements.

https://github.com/PhilippBaschke/acf-pro-installer/issues/44 describes the differences concisely.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30259823)

Comment: @Cyclonecode thanks for the feedback. I added a line of code that fixes one of the issues with the tool.